# Duplicate generated class gradle output (build/...) vs intellij output (out/...)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, lombok

I'm using intellij (2019.1.1) for a java gradle (5.4.1) project and use lombok (1.18.6) for autogenerating code. Intellij puts generated sources under `out/production/classes/generated/...` and gradle puts them under `build/generated/sources/...`

This is fine, and I like that intellij keeps it's own build artifacts separate from gradles, however, intellij seems to look in both directories when running projects and it complains about the duplicate generated classes. 
What is the best practice for using intellij with gradle and autogenerated sources? Do you:

1. tell intellij to output to the same directory as gradle (this
   could lead to odd behaviour if a process outside of intellij updates
   a file under build/)
2. tell intellij to perform all tasks with
   gradle (i hear this is slower than intellij's make)
3. tell intellij
   to simply ignore the 'build' directory (how do you even do this? and
   why does intellij even care about 'build/' when it knows it outputs
   to 'out/')

**UPDATE**: to clarify the situation, the issue is NOT with lombok autogenerated code, it is with hibernate-jpamodelgen. The problem remains the same (duplicate generated sources) but I want to clarify the it is the sources generated by jpamodelgen and not lombok.

**UPDATE 2**: I have tried the following configuration in an attempt to tell intellij where the generated sources live and also to tell intellij to ignore the build directory. Sadly, this did not work (still get duplicate class error on the generated source files).

```
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    idea {
        module {
            sourceDirs += file('out/production/classes/generated')
            generatedSourceDirs += file('out/production/classes/generated')
            excludeDirs += file('build')
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**:
Tried the advice from M.Riccuiti and deleted build/, out/, .idea/, .gradle/ and reimported the gradle project but intellij is still seeing the generated sources in the build/ directory.

[image: generated sources root]

[image: annotation processor settings]

[image: gradle settings]

[image: gradle runner settings]

Comment: I got this same problem with "duplicated class" (generated classes for QueryDSL and MapStruct annotation plugins) after I migrated from Gradle 4.10 to Gradle 5.x : before Gradle 5.x IDEA was using another target directory for generated classes under `/out` and strangely these classes were not detected as duplicated.. do you use Gradle IDEA plugin to configure the IDEA project? and did you enable "delegate build/test to build tool" option in IDEA ?

Comment: I could solve this issue by configuring properly the `idea.module.generatedSourceDirs`  and `idea.module.sourceDirs`  properties , setting value to `out/production/classes/generated/`.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I did not enable delegate build/test to build tool (which is option #2 in my list) because I have heard that it may be slower. I will look into setting the sourcedirs via the idea plugin.

Comment: Can you provide such a sample project? Interesting how you end up with two build output directories if you do not use "Delegate" to Gradle mode.

Comment: @Andrey I have two output directories because I often develop from both intellij and from the bash shell. When I'm not in a UI context I simply use the gradle commands to build and execute, but if I have intellij handy I use it.

Comment: @Andrey I have similar issue, see sample project here https://github.com/mricciuti/sample-springboot-gradle-idea .  you can easily reproduce the problem by commenting the `idea.module` configuration from `build.gradle` :  after importing the project in IDEA, first build with Gradle (from IDEA Gradle tool), then build project (CTRL+F9)

Comment: `first build with Gradle` then I see why you would get two directories. If you do not mix Gradle and IDE build - IDE creates only one output directory. Why do you build by both Gradle and IDE?

Comment: @Andrey as Andrew already mentioned sometimes you want/need to perform some gradle tasks (like publishing, releasing, or any other ) outside the IDEA, so you can expect that  /build directory exists. but there is no reason that this /build directory is taken into account by IDEA when you disable "delegate to Gradle" option.

Comment: FYI the problem is not reproducible for me with 2019.1.1 version: https://i.imgur.com/JDbqHjO.png

Comment: @Andrey this seems to be a vicious behaviour/bug.. I could not even reproduce the problem with my own github project => I made new simplier project in order to reproduce: see https://github.com/mricciuti/idea-gradle-duplicated-class  . See the README for steps to reproduce

Comment: Thank you! Filled the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211818 Please follow.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that finally worked for me.  The trick is to notice that when gradle generates the classes,  it puts them in:

```
build\generated\sources\annotationProcessor\java\main\com...
```

but intellij has the production sources directory set to "generated" in this case,  the sources go to:

```
build\generated\sources\annotationProcessor\java\main\generated\com...
```

if you compile with gradle first and then use idea,  you get both of them, which causes the problem!

To solve this,  replace "generated" and "generated_test" in the intellij annotation processors "production sources directory " and "test sources directory " configuration with just a "/"   this makes both gradle and intellij generate the sources in the SAME directory, overwriting each other as needed.   Also make sure that the "store generated sources relative to" is set to "module content root" and REBUILD the application to clear out any other sources.

Comment: that is true if you want gradle and intellij to both output to /build. I am trying to keep intellij output (/out) and gradle output (/build) separate.

Comment: I think you can get that kind of behavior by just "excluding" the build directory entirely using the "mark directory as.." function in intellij  and set compiler annotation output to "build output" directory. 

This should avoid including anything from the "build" directory. I also believe that the "exclude" signal should stay intact even when re-importing gradle.build file.

i've been strongly discouraged from using the idea-gradle plugin and have found that trying to mess with the idea default setup causes more headaches than ever expected.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I proposed in previous comment was working fine in IDEA 2018.3.x but after upgrading to IDEA 2019.1 I again got this duplicate class exception...

Below is a working solution to make this work with Gradle 5.x (tested with 5.4) and IDEA 2019.1 , to implement your solution #3 which I think is the best option (do not mix gradle & idea generated output directories, and do not delegate IDEA action do Gradle )

The key point is to use `excludeDirs` property from `idea.module` extension to make IDEA ignore generated sources managed by Gradle under `build/generated/sources/...`

```
ext {
    // path to Gradle generated main sources directory
    gradleGeneratedMainSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/"
    // path to Gradle generated test sources directory
    gradleGeneratedTestSourcesDir = "$buildDir/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test/"
    // path to IDEA generated sources directory
    ideaGeneratedSourcesDir = "$projectDir/out/production/classes/generated"        
}

idea {
    module {
        // exclude main & test sources generated by Gradle from project source directories
        excludeDirs += file(gradleGeneratedMainSourcesDir)
        excludeDirs += file(gradleGeneratedTestSourcesDir)

        // include generated sources directory managed by IDEA
        sourceDirs += file(ideaGeneratedSourcesDir)
        generatedSourceDirs += file(ideaGeneratedSourcesDir)
    }
}
```

See complete sample project based on this configuration here : https://github.com/mricciuti/sample-springboot-gradle-idea

Comment: I gave this a shot and it is not working. Intellij is seeing $buildDir/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/ as a source directory even though it's in the excluded directories. If I inspect the module in intellij, it has this directory listed for exclusion, yet it also has it listed under source directories. I feel like it's an order of operations thing where intellij is favouring source directories over exclusions.

Comment: I suggest you re-import  completely your project into IDEA, after you manually delete  .idea/, .gradle/, /out and /build directories. Then, first build with Gradle (from IDEA gradle tool), and check that `$buildDir/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main` is not marked as "generated source" dir in the project directory tree. Only after, make the project built by IDEA. hope this helps.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Sorry for 'atting' you, but in a big project we also have a lot of issues with generated meta models not being found which are indeed made bu jpamodelgen. I've noticed that our project is adding a 'generated' directory under 'build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/'. Which seems our is expecting the sources to be. If I change all these setting to main intelliJ is still erroring on us.
We have gradle delegated to gradle (not intelliJ) and we really don't need the generated sources to be in 'out'. I am so confused.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue meanwhile? I am using 2021.2.2 and still got these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter to IntelliJ Settings (Preferences):

Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner

Then you tick the checkbox **Delegate IDE build/run action to Gradle**

Finally, you clean and build again. The issues will be resolved.